# Pycharms module successfully downloaded but not found

Tags: python, libraries, ide, pycharm, dependencies

I've gone through just about every post on this topic and none of the solutions have worked thus far.

I recently made the mistake of trying to switch python versions and my project in pycharms went from working fine to not being able to recognize any of the modules installed. I've tried reinstalling both pycharms and python, I've gone through all of the posts regarding the project interpreters, I cannot seem to find a solution. Most concerning part is this is persistent through the IDE and even new venv's are unable to recognize any modules, even if "successfully" installed.

Any ideas?

Example error:
    from nltk import word_tokenize
ImportError: No module named nltk

[image: The most common solutions call for this usually]

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly do you get `ImportError`? Do you run a script or manually type the offending import in PyCharm's Python Console? Both the Console and a Run Configuration for a given file may use a different interpreter. Make sure it is the one you expect:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: After playing with the interpreters some more, I seem to have it working again. Not sure exactly what did it but it's rolling now. Thank you